# Why does Scala use a reversed shebang (!#) instead of just setting interpreter to scala

Tags: bash, scala, sh

The scala documentation shows that the way to create a scala script is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#
/* Script here */
```

I know that this executes scala with the name of the script file and the arguments passed to it, and that the scala command apparently knows to read a file that starts like this and ignore everything up to the reversed shebang `!#`

My question is: is there any reason why I should use this (rather verbose) format for a scala script, rather than just:

```
#!/bin/env scala
/* Script here */
```

This, as far a I can tell from a quick test, does exactly the same thing, but is less verbose.

Comment: The only thing I got is it is obviously more flexible and lets you set environment variables (e.g. `_JAVA_OPTIONS`) prior to script launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How old is the documentation?  Usually, this sort of thing (often referred to as 'the exec hack') was recommended before `/bin/env` was common, and this was the best way to get the functionality.  Note that `/usr/bin/env` is more common than `/bin/env`, and ought to be used instead.

Comment: This is in both the old documentation and the current documentation. http://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html

Comment: By the time Scala was invented, `/usr/bin/env` (it's `/usr/bin/env`, not `/bin/env`) had been firmly established for over a decade, and I doubt that there's any platform where Scala and shebang works but not `/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: @Giles `/bin/env` is common enough (indeed, even though Linux standardized `/usr/bin/env`, on Red Hat `/usr/bin/env` is a sym link to `/bin/env`, or at least was the last time I looked), but since the OP mentions `/bin/env` it is pointless to talk about `/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: @Gilles `env` was introduced with 4.4 BSD, which dates to 1994. GNU's copyright dates to 2010, though.

Comment: There is no `/bin/env` on my system (it's `/usr/bin/env`, and there's no symlink).

Comment: As I recall, the LSB codified `/usr/bin/env`, but sus doesn't specify the path.  RedHat uses `/bin/env` with a symbolic link from `/usr/bin`.  Searching just now to find more info, I see the headline of this article https://lwn.net/Articles/658809/ from late last year and give up all hope. :(

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral `/usr/bin/env` is the majority by far. [Sven Mascheck](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#env) cites SCO OpenServer and Unicos as having `/bin/env`, I know there's also NeXTSTEP. The only one that still counts as extant today is SCO and even that isn't exactly common. Linux, *BSD, SunOS, Solaris, HP-UX, AIX all have `/usr/bin/env` (sometimes alongside `/bin/env`, but often not). `/usr/bin/env` is not a Linuxism.

Comment: @Gilles Hey, leave me out of the `/bin/env` vs `/usr/bin/env` discussion. Though now I vaguely recall `env` used to have an issue that made using it for everything not a good idea. Anyway, _my_ point is that `env` (whatever the path is) was _not_ that widely available or used by 2004/05.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Your point would be wrong then. By 1998, which is when I discovered unices other than Linux, `#!/usr/bin/env` was already very common; coping without it was something you did only if you needed portability to exotic or ancient systems.

Comment: @Gilles You being a big fan of it didn't make it common.

Answer (score 1):

Note that it's `/usr/bin/env`, not `/bin/env`.

There are no benefits to using an intermediate shell instead of `/usr/bin/env`, except running in some rare antique Unix variants where `env` isn't in `/usr/bin`. Well, technically SCO still exists, but does Scala even run there?

However the advantage of the shell variant is that it gives an opportunity to tune what is executed, for example to add elements to `PATH` or `CLASSPATH`, or to add options such as `-savecompiled` to the interpreter (as shown in the [manual](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs-2.10.2/manual/html/scala.html)). This may be why the documentation suggests the shell form.

I am not on the Scala development team and I don't know what the historical motivation for the Scala documentation was.

Comment: Pedantry over which bin env is in isn't relevant to the question, as some systems configure their `bin`s differently, and this question isn't about that. Information about other configuration that can be done in the specialized variant is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Scala did not always support `/usr/bin/env`. No particular reason for it, just, I imagine, the person who wrote the shell scripting support was not familiar with that syntax, back in the mid 00's. The documentation followed what was supported, and I added `/usr/bin/env` support at some point (iirc), but never bothered changing the documentation, it would seem.